# CloudFoundry microbosh unable to deploy on AWS

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, cloud-foundry

I've followed the "minimal AWS deployment" guide here https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-release/tree/master/example_manifests to try CloudFoundry.

I understand that I have to install the bosh_cli_plugin_micro, but when I run this on an AWS Ubuntu 14.04 VM:

```
gem install bosh_cli_plugin_micro
```

I get:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::DependencyError)
    Unable to resolve dependencies: blobstore_client requires aws-sdk-resources (= 2.2.0); aws-sdk requires aws-sdk-v1 (= 1.60.2)
```

Installing the AWS ruby sdk doesn't solve the problem. I suspect it's a problem of the aws sdk being a newer version than the one the micro bosh cli expects. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

One way to ensure you get a consistent set of gems would be to create a `Gemfile` like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'bosh_cli'
gem 'bosh_cli_plugin_micro'
```

and then run the `bundle` command from the same working directory as where your `Gemfile` is placed.  To make sure you're always using the right version of the CLI and plugin, prepend commands with `bundle exec`, e.g.

```
$ bundle exec bosh micro deploy /path/to/stemcell
```

You may even wish to alias `bosh` to `bundle exec bosh`.